# How to call java code and javascript code in the same form with jsp

Tags: javascript, java, forms, jsp, captcha

So I currently have a problem where I have a form that contains two inputs for username and password, a captcha (`<div>`) and an `input` of type `submit` that acts as a button. When this submit button is hit I want it to check the captcha to see if it is empty. If it is not empty, I want it to then call the other java code that authenticates a user.

My jsp form looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- more scripts / google api js are here -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function get_action(form) {
        var v = grecaptcha.getResponse();
        if(v.length === 0) {
           document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML="Login failed: Empty captcha";
           return false;
        } else { 
           return true; 
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="login" method="post" onsubmit="return get_action(this);">
       <input type="text" id="email" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.email)}" required>
       <input type="text" id="password" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.password)}" required>
       <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxx"></div>
       <input class="submit_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
       <span class="error"${error.invalid}</span>
       <div id="captcha" class="captchaError"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my login servlet that is supposed to do the verification of the user is as follows:

```
@WebServlet("/login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private LoginDAO loginDAO;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        Map<String, String> error = new HashMap<String,String>();
        request.setAttribute("error",error);

        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        // Verify re-captcha
        String gRecaptchaResponse = request.getParameter("captcha");
        boolean verify = VerifyRecaptcha.verify(gRecaptchaResponse);
        if(!verify) {
            error.put("captcha","You seem to be a robot. Try to use the captcha again");
        }
        if(error.isEmpty()) {
            loginDAO = new LoginDAO();
            try {
                List<Customer> customer = new ArrayList<Customer>();
                customer = loginDAO.validate(email,password);
                if(customer.isEmpty()) {
                    error.put("invalid","Invalid email or password");
                }
                if(error.isEmpty()) { // no errors, proceed
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                    Customer user = customer.get(0);
                    session.setAttribute("user",user);
                    response.sendRedirect("main");
                    return;
                }
                request.getRequestDispatcher("login").forward(request,response);
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                throw new ServletException("Could not check login",e);
            }
            loginDAO.closeLoginDAO();
        }
    }
}
```

Where loginDAO just checks the username and password against a database.

What is weird is that last night everything was working fine. The only thing I did was move around the java files into subdirectories. But I updated the `web.xml` file to make sure nothing was wrong.

Now I have a feeling that the `onsubmit=` portion of the `form` is screwing with the java class. Does anyone know what the right thing to do is for form validation with javascript and java? I unfortunately need some kind of javascript for the reCaptcha because otherwise the user can submit an empty captcha.

Comment: In `doGet()`, you forward to `login.jsp`. In `doPost()` you forward to `login`. Not sure if it's a typo in the question but it could be causing problems. Side note: take care to close your loginDAO resources prior to doing the forward or redirect.

Answer (score 0):

In your jsp file `var v = grecaptcha.getResponse();` ,you lose the defination of `grecaptcha`,this will cause an error.

Comment: It doesn't seem to affect anything. I mean it still goes to a blank page. Also inspecting the page when in chrome doesn't show any errors for the javascript portion.